# Creating windows 8 backup on skydrive

Tags: windows-8, backup, onedrive

I purchased a HP Pavalion preinstalled with windows 8 OS. No external media was provided with the laptop. Is it possible to store complete windows 8 backup in cloud such that I can perform clean windows 8 install in future,if necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SkyDrive has a file size limit in which you run into. The web version allows 100MB and the Desktop client supports 2GB. So this is not possible.

Create a backup and store it on an external USB 3.0 HDD or Flash drive.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to realize your request is to get a system CD. If you insist to get it into an external hard drive or an cloud drive, of course both of this two methods can do. Cloud drive is more safe as well as convenient than HDD, However, the OS of windows 8 is ususally very space consuming. many cloud account provider only provide 5 or 10GB's free space. BUT, i recommond you a APP, you can first register several free cloud accounts, and use this APP, named [MULTCLOUD](https://www.multcloud.com/multcloud.html) to combine your five or more accounts into one.